# TFS Branch Diagrams

Tags: tfs, branch, diagram

Has anyone got any great ideas or experience around easily producing Branch Diagrams against TFS?

Answer (score 3):

TFS 2008 [does not include](http://tfsvtreebrowse.codeplex.com/) this functionality, so you'll have to resort to a plug-in/add-on.  I haven't found any mature projects that produce branch or version diagrams, though many allow browsing of branch/version trees.

- [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/downloads/index.htm) has a History Sidekick that includes version tree browsing
- [Vertigo](http://tfsvtreebrowse.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Vision%20Statement) plans to include version tree browsing for individual files, as well as branches, but is [still in alpha](http://tfsvtreebrowse.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=208).

Answer (score 1):

Very similar questions already answered:

[View TFS checkin history through merges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45882/view-tfs-checkin-history-across-branches)
[TFS Branch/Merge meets History View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681630/tfs-branch-merge-meets-history-view)

If you don't mind setting up a 2nd server just for playing with branch visualization, TFS 2010 Beta 1 is going to render by far the best diagrams.